# Is there a way I can prgrammatically enable a draw a polygon on the leaflet map by clicking a button with using the toolbar using react-leaftlet

Tags: react-leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet-draw

I To be aable to draw polygon just like it function in leaftlet-control without using the tool bar provided by the leaflet control and using react-leaflet library  to achieve it.

Here a snippet library I tried using but does not work
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FeatureGroup, MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap, useMapEvents, Polygon } from 'react-leaflet';
import EditControl from './EditControl';